# Attach a related property in the CollectionChanged event of entity object

Tags: entity-framework, observablecollection

Any help gratefully received on a little issue I have.

I have an entity framework class

```
public partial class BookingProduct
{
    public BookingProduct()
    {
        this.BookingDesigns = new ObservableCollection<BookingDesign>();
        this.BookingDesigns.CollectionChanged += ContentCollectionChanged;
    }

    public int BookingProductId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<BookingDesign> BookingDesigns { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve Product here
    }
}
```

In my application I am retrieving a BookingProduct with BookingDesigns included from the database but not the Product. I'm wondering if within the entity class there is a way to retrieve the Product from with the ContentCollectionChanged event?

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you could simply access the property to have it lazy load from within the `ContentCollectionChanged` method, but I question why you would want to do that.  At best the solution would be confusing - why manage the state of the `Product` property in a method meant to handle changes to an unrelated collection?

Comment: Hi Moho, thanks for the reply. I actually have lazy loading disabled and need the Product to update the Price when the BookingDesign collection is changed...confusing I know ;-)